# Accesspress submenu font color

Tags: css

There seems to be a issue with uncode pro accesspress theme and the ability to change the sub menu font color.

Can't seem to figure out how to change font color of the submenu to black with CSS.
Please see the rectangle tab as reference.
[Temp Domain Site](http://bn1.500.myftpupload.com/)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I have added that this is an issue when using uncode pro theme to help direct more people to solve this problem in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere, in your style (line 1265 of style.css obviously from your link), you have

```
.header2 #site-navigation ul#primary-menu ul li:hover a, .header2 #site-navigation #primary-menu ul ul li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Problem is since sub-menu (with white text) contains  tag, and since you are hovering li of the parent menu, the white color is applied altough you are not hovering the direct li parent of  of sub menu.

You need to restrict to the direct li parent with following css (and by using **>**)
And because the framework you are using only allows to add some CSS, you'll need to refine the default hovering definition with black color, like

```
.header2 #site-navigation ul#primary-menu ul li:hover a, .header2 #site-navigation #primary-menu ul ul li:hover a {
            color: #22272c;
        }
.header2 #site-navigation ul#primary-menu ul li:hover>a, .header2 #site-navigation #primary-menu ul ul li:hover>a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```

Comment: I have added the additional css via the "additional css", as seen in the standard Uncode theme options. https://imgur.com/ORvGvMZ  to no avail. I'd prefer to add css in this section so as not to lose custom css when updating theme. (I have not created child theme yet)

Comment: Ok. As you can not update the existing style, but only override it, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by submenu you mean the drop down menus, the font is already black. Try refreshing your browsers cache at it may not be updating locally. Also post some code it makes debugging easier.

Comment: Yes, drop down menu.. but it's the sub menu under the shapes.. i.e. 12x24 rectangle kits. Cache flushed and still see the following https://imgur.com/onEr6AK .. Checked with a different computer and browser and doesn't appear to be black either

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style in your CSS:

```
.menu-item a {
    color: #22272c;
}
```